# Can't log in to StackExchange Chat, stackauth.com 404s

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, connectivity

- `http://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global` doesn't log me in. It [just sits there](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/1302/aadc996be1534a45a98b2fa.png) trying to connect to something, and eventually gives up on that and does nothing else.
- `http://chat.stackexchange.com/help` says I can't connect to stackauth.com. [That test fails in both Firefox and Chrome](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/2210/6b271045cec743628480bdd.png). All the other tests pass. This isn't an iframe issue as I don't have anything that blocks iframes. In fact, I simply can't connect to StackAuth.com. [Here's an image of it 404ing in Firefox and Chrome](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/4444/fa0b81fdcf81456a8013a9a.png)
  .
- I tried the chat-stackexchange-login button approach: in this case, https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login. I [accessed that page just fine](http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/6397/44e1864560a64209b09045b.png) but when I click the button I get an express route to [an error page courtesy of Picard and his crew](http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/9528/cc7a436d27424c54b684758.png).

So now I'm here writing this out. I don't think this is a one-off issue. I remember a month or two ago I couldn't log into chat either - the login page doesn't do anything (just like now) but at that point I didn't look into it further.

I'm located in Brisbane, Australia.

Comment: Yeah, busted up for me too. [And not *just* me...](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/stackauth.com)

Comment: @Shog9 And now it's just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crack Stack Exchange SysAdmin team appears to have fixed this.

Blame-thank Zypher!

Comment: Dammit Zypher! Thanks! For nothing! Except fixing the server!

Comment: What, no status-completed?

Comment: geez, man... I'm probably gonna just delete this tomorrow... You think I have *boxes* of red tags laying around to just waste on stuff?

Comment: @VxJasonxV happy?